# How to install gpg2 via homebrew?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I want to install `gpg2`, however when I run
`brew install gpg2` (also tried
`brew install gnupg2`)
it always installs `gpg` instead of `gpg2`. 
Currently, running the `gpg` command works but not `gpg2`.
How can I resolve this?

EDIT:
Tried `brew install gnupg gnupg2` too but didn't work

Answer (score 45):

Homebrew just links the `gpg2` binary as `gpg`.

Your `gpg` command is actually already the correct and expected version.

Comment: It does not look like Homebrew does a `gpg2` symlink (anymore).

Answer (score 29):

Installing gpg is enough according to the [online package browser for Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/gnupg):

*gnupg

Also known as: gnupg2, gnupg@2.2, gpg, gpg2
 
Formerly known as: gnupg2*

Run: gpg --version in the terminal to check you have the right version.

Comment: What output of `gpg --version` would successfully indicate that I have gpg2?

Comment: @JonSchneider as of today the current stable version of gpg is 2.2.26. Source https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/gnupg

Answer (score 0):

I have also homebrew and can work with:

```
gpg -d file.dat.gpg
```

I have installed `pinentry` but this does not work. You must put the password
of `file.dat.gpg` in a terminal entry.